# Does Windows require IE to access ftp sites?

Tags: windows-explorer, internet-explorer, ftp

If I remove Internet Explorer from my computer, can I still access FTP sites using Windows Explorer ?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this doesn't directly answer your question I asked a question about removing IE once before and was generally told it was a bad idea.  See link for details...

[Is it ok to remove Internet Explorer from my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/131976/is-it-ok-to-remove-internet-explorer-from-my-computer)

Comment: This is more of a hypothetical question. I just want to know more about the structure of Windows Explorer.